# How to change the color of the cell table based on score in database?

Tags: php

I wanted to display color in the table based on the Score result in the database. For example, if >=20, it shows red. I read one of the articles and i tried using his code, it works but I still need additional code to do the ifelse statement. The problem is i do not know the syntax how to continue.

How do i continue with the syntax in the table form? Like if i also want to check if $score >=30 then it shows green.

```html
<td <?php if($score >=20): ?> style="background-color: red;" <?php endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $score; ?>
</td>
```

The code works find but i need the example syntax to do the "elseif" statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to handle this would be to extract the logic out into a function, and then just call that in your view.

For example:

```php
function tableColor($score) {
    switch ($score) {
        case $score >= 30:
            return 'background-color: green;';
        case $score >= 20:
            return 'background-color: red;';
        default:
            return '';
    }
}
?>

<td style="<?= tableColor($score) ?>">
    <?php echo $score; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: What should be included inside the function? Do you have an example?

Comment: What do you mean? I added an example of the function in my code above.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. Can you explain the code u wrote line by line to me as I am new to PHP thanks

Comment: I have a for loop below that, i dont know why my table will just show the same color for score 0 and 20